# Unable to access an endpoint in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API Controller, from View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a WEB Api project in ASP.NET Core 3.1; I am trying to use the same controller for showing a view and also for endpoints. The view will allow a user to input DB connection parameters and POST to an endpoint in the controller, which will write these settings to a file.

I was able to show the view only after deriving from Controller (changed from controller base). This link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1, says if you plan to use the same controller for views and API, you should derive from Controller.

I am able to show my view but I am unable to post (using ajax) to an endpoint in the same controller. I am getting the following error:-

*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400.*

[image: Information from the console (chrome)]

My controller is named Connection Controller and my endpoint is SaveConnection()

[image: Connection Controller]

I am trying to Post to the SaveConnection endpoint using ajax, but I am getting the error (from console above).

My code in the view looks like below.

[image: Javascript code in the View]

It looks like when posting to the endpoint, Connection/SaveConnection, I am unable to reach the endpoint, hence the 400 message.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize your obj first.
Can you try replacing the line "`data:obj,`" with "`data:JSON.stringify(obj),`".

Comment: Let me mention that I have upgraded this API from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET 3.1. The code was running OK in .NET Core 2.2

I am thinking that the issue could be routing and that could be why the controller is not recognized as a 'resource'. That is just speculation and I could be wrong of course.

In the meantime, I am still researching for a solution.

Zekeriya kocairi, passing the object in the form it is, should work just fine. I have the same code running in a .NET Core 2.2 web API with no issues at all.

Comment: Ok. You may evolve your solution step by step. I would first try to send post request to an endpoint with no parameter and no security attribute then you can be sure is your problem really about routing. But it's probably with parameter. You may also add [Frombody] before your parameter. It should be mandatory. This attribute should be mandatory since you have [ApiController] attirbute on Controller

Comment: Zekeriya Kocairi, you are RIGHT!!!. Your advice pointed me in the right direction. In the view, I have altered my form so that the form tag has asp-action = "SaveConnection" and asp-controller="Connection". My button is of type="submit" instead of "button". My parameter for the SaveConnection Action is [FromForm]. I can now access my action, The only downside is that I am no longer using ajax for posting. But my jquery validation is working OK though. Thank You!!

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved your issue. Good luck with your following challenges.